# MuPDF Cocoapods Installation Error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, epub, mupdf

After researching on what library to use in one of my projects for epub reader, I decided to use MuPDF. I integrated it using Cocoapods, but when I build the app, it gives me a couple of errors on `_math.h_` file on lines 36 and 73. I have attached the screenshots for reference. It would be of great help if anyone here can help me build the app after integrating MuPDF without any error. [line 36](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu5CQ.png)

Comment: Make sure you are working on .xcworkspace not .xcodeproject

Comment: Yep. I'm working on .xcworkspace.

Comment: check your cocopods version if it is latest or not

Comment: I'm using the latest cocoapods version.

Comment: I tried to download it using cocopods. succussfully installed. Build also succeeded.

Comment: I'm on Cocoapods 0.38.2 and Xcode 7.2. Are you on a different setup?

Comment: Am I missing any files that needs to be imported here or steps here? I created a new obj-c app, pod init, added MuPDF to pods, pod install, opened .xcworkspace, build the project, still the same, got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being hit by a not-backwards-compatible change that took place in CocoaPods 0.39 ( https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/4057 ).

Can you upgrade your CocoaPod to 0.39? (`gem update cocoa pods`) If you do so and then run `pod install` that should fix it.

If you can't upgrade to 0.39, you could use the 1.7 podspec mupdf, which is compatible with CocoaPod 0.38.

There's an example project that uses the MuPDF pod spec here:

https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example

(To try and prevent this problem in the future I just pushed a new pod, 1.8.2, that has a cocoapods_version >= 0.39 restriction in the podspec.)

Comment: thanks. it worked. My real project is on Swift, so I added the import lines on the bridging header file, the problem now is, it's popping up the missing fitz.h file

Comment: @hnmpk I've not tried that, but it may just be a case of adding a recursive include for the Pods folder to the 'User Header Search Paths' in your project (see http://swiftalicio.us/2014/11/using-cocoapods-from-swift/ )

Comment: Double checked my 'User Header Search Paths' and I don't have recursive include for Pods. I have updated my Pods to 0.39, ran pod install, add import line on the swift file where I want to use MuPDF, _import MuPDF_, it's giving me another error, which is, `Could not build Objective-C module MuPDF'

Comment: @hnmpk There's not really enough information there for me to figure out what's going on. Can you push your test project to github temporarily?

Comment: @paulo do you fix this problem with 'Could not build Objective-C module MuPDF'???